# Who are professional Hindus here?

Tags: discussion

Sanathan Dharma aka Hinduism consists of a huge and rich corpus of scriptures and traditions. There are plenty of gurus, gods, sects, branches, and others.  So, In general, our site needs to be active all the time. But, unfortunately, in general, the elite Hindus are very less and the few elite people may be busy. The same reflects on our site.

I am in academics and Hinduism is not my profession in any way. It is my all-time interest and so I spend more time on Hinduism-related content. Similarly, I saw other people who are doing other professions and are contributing to our site.

Since there are fewer knowledgeable or professional users on our site, I personally saw over time that there are some users who try to increase the site content with less researched wrong answers or biased answers which are not useful for our site improvement in any way.

In this context, I want to know whether there are any professional Hindus here. I am asking for people like pandits, astrologists, ayurvedists, purohits, Sanskrit experts, archakas, Hindu acharyas, researchers on Hinduism, etc.,

Please answer this question if you are a professional Hindu and mention the subject in which you are an expert if possible.

Comment: There was a user called Partha Bannerjee (Partha Pratim) who was some sort of a professional. He has written books on Hinduism, and has translated scriptures (he has degrees in Sanskrit) and I think he was also involved with a Temple in Calcutta. So he is possibly into Paurahitya too. He was a prolific user and a friend but sadly he left the site.